# How to reference variables (either JVM or environment) in TeamCity's Tomcat config (server.xml)?

Tags: tomcat, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I'm trying to set up TeamCity server with HTTPS support. To do so, I must specify keystore file path and keystore password in `…/conf/server.xml`.

My current Connector is defined there as follows:

```
<Connector 
    …(some more attributes here)…
    keystoreFile="${keystore.path}" keystorePassword="${keystore.pass}"/>
```

Whenever I run `env TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS="-Dkeystore.path='$KEYSTORE_PATH'" ./bin/configtest.sh`, I'm getting the error like this:

```
WARNING: configured file:[/home/app/teamcity/${keystore.path}] does not exist.
```

(`/home/app/teamcity/` is where TeamCity was unpacked)
(KEYSTORE_PATH is a correctly defined environment variable, I can write a specific value instead, the result is the same)

That means, `TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS` is not really used for setting arbitrary JVM options for TeamCity server, right?

If so, how can I pass some values and use them in the config? I think hardcoding them is bad.

(if that does matter, I use Ubuntu 14.04 here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS` is used to pass additional JVM options, but only does so when you run the `teamcity-server.sh` script. The `configtest.sh` is part of the Tomcat distro and in this case is not aware of the TeamCity variable. If you try with `JAVA_OPTS` instead, you can validate:

```
env JAVA_OPTS="-Dkeystore.path='$KEYSTORE_PATH'" ./bin/configtest.sh
```

Optionally you could add this line to `configtest.sh` before the `exec` of `catalina.sh`:

`export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS"`